# Can I use Visual Studio for developing Linux C or C++?

Tags: linux, visual-studio

I have to develop something in Linux(CentOS 6.5) Environment using C or C++ language with many of libraries for linux.
As you know, CentOS is not GUI. So, I want to use Microsoft Visual Studio for my work. It's OK even if use just VS as the Editor.
I mean that I like the features of IDE visual studio(intellisense, debugger, and so on).

I have Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2013 Professional.

Comment: Yes you can, if you have a [*cross compiler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) that generates Linux binaries. And you have to do it in Windows, as Visual Studio is a Windows program (but there are [ways](https://www.winehq.org/) [around](https://www.virtualbox.org/) that). And you *can't* use the debugger. There are however many [Integrated Development Environments (IDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) available for Linux environments, that have just about all features of Visual Studio.

Comment: Another option is to write code which works for both platforms: usually (unless you are writing drivers or so) a large part of your program is platform independent and compiles with any compiler for any platform. Especially in modern C++ where the standard library already has threads covered. Make the build system take care of selecting the remaining platform dependent source, if any. Then you can program, run, debug natively in VS or wahetever IDE fits you best. And you get the benefit of running the same code through different compilers which sometimes reveals interesting bugs :]

Comment: I wish to use remote connecting to Linux by VS, if the feature exists in VS and it is possible. I saw that use 'build command line' from somewhere of the Internet for the similar subject.

Comment: A question like this is more likely to be closed. But for your info, JetBrains CLion is going to be available soon, and it is simply the cross platform IDE for C/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, in fact, if you have setup a VM machine, you can even directly include the C++ include library of Linux (However, this only works for write code, not work with compiling). You could also setup CYGWIN or MINGW for referencing the header of Linux platform.

In fact, for myself, I switched to QtCreator as a cross platform C++ IDE, it also has auto-complete and debug features.